# Unable to manipulate Imported Object menu (Unity)

Tags: unity, 3d-meshes, importing

I've imported a model, but for some reason I can't edit any settings under the Imported Object menu, such as the Mesh Filter or the Mesh Renderer.

See this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7ZYR.png for a screencap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do that, make the model into a [prefab.](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/Prefabs.html). Then drag that prefab into the `Hierarchy` view. Then you should see either:

[image]

If the model is skinned and:

[image]

If it is not skinned.

Comment: Oops, sorry :).Temporarily forgot to do that.